# Wrong decimal places after parsing

Tags: c#, parsing

I'm trying to load some XY-coordinates from a asc-file. It looks like this:

> -55.988544        9382
>   -53.395804          9403
>   -50.804601          9433

Then I am converting the coordinates to floats. But somehow f.e. for the first value I get **"-55988544.0"** instead of **"-55.988544"**.

Here is the code:

```
 private void btngettext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader objStream = new StreamReader("C:\\...\\.asc");

        firstLine = objStream.ReadLine();

        int i = 0;

        /*Split String on Tab,
         * will separate words*/
        string[] words = firstLine.Split('\t');

        richTextBox1.Text = words[0];

        foreach(string word in words)
        {
            if(word != "")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(word); //the value of the string is "-55.988544" here 
                //value = float.Parse(word); tried both
                value = Convert.ToSingle(word); //here the float value is "-55988544.0"
                Console.WriteLine(value.ToString());// "-5,598854E+07"
                xyArray[0,i] = value;

                i++;
            }
        }

    }
```

Besides, if I would use objStream.ReadToEnd() or .Read(), how could iterate through lines. Read the values in the first line, save them and proceed to the next line.

Thanks in advance,

BC++

Comment: Verify your culture settings, particularly the thousands separator.

Comment: It's treating the . as a thousand seperator, not a decimal point due to your locale settings

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Still nobody any idea how to iterate trough lines and always read out the coordinate pairs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like your application is running under a culture where "." is a thousands separator rather than a decimal separator. If the source file always uses a ".", then it is better to parse with:

```
float.Parse(word, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

That will ensure that the parse uses a "." no matter what the machine culture is.

Answer (score 3):

It probably is an issue with the culture settings. Try the following:

```
var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
value = float.Parse(word, culture);
```

Answer (score 2):

If your data uses a known, fixed notation for decimal separator etc you should not rely on the defaults of the reading PC. Use

```
   value = float.Parse(word, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```